# symfony user query return fields I don't specify when I am logged In

Tags: json, symfony, doctrine, fosuserbundle, dql

In my symfony app, using fosuserbundle too, this is a **DQL** query I create to recover all data I need concerning user:

```
public function getAlluserNeedlesInfo()
{
    return
      $this->getEntityManager()
           ->createQuery(
              'SELECT partial u.{id, username, email, roles, enabled, createdAt, updatedAt}, partial c.{id, companySiret, companyName, professional, firstName, lastName, slug, createdAt, updatedAt}
               FROM AppBundle:User u
               JOIN u.consumer c
               ORDER BY u.id ASC'
           )
          ->getResult();
}
```

This is my controller method code:

```
public function usersAction()
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $users = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:User')->getAlluserNeedlesInfo();
    $serializedEntity = $this->container->get('serializer')->serialize($users, 'json');
    return new Response($serializedEntity);
}
```

For now all works well, this is the results in json format returning by my controller method:

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "username": "test",
    "email": "test@test.com",
    "enabled": true,
    "roles": [],
    "consumer": {
        "id": 1,
        "professional": false,
        "last_name": "TEST",
        "first_name": "test",
        "slug": "test-test",
        "created_at": "2016-10-07T03:22:32+0200",
        "updated_at": "2016-10-07T17:42:17+0200"
    },
    "created_at": "2016-10-02T07:28:28+0200",
    "updated_at": "2016-10-09T01:05:04+0200"
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "username": "admin",
    "email": "admin@test.com",
    "enabled": true,
    "roles": ["ROLE_ADMIN"],
    "consumer": {
        "id": 2,
        "company_name": "admin",
        "company_siret": "01234567890006",
        "professional": true,
        "last_name": "ADMIN",
        "first_name": "Admin",
        "slug": "admin-admin",
        "created_at": "2016-10-06T08:45:23+0200",
        "updated_at": "2016-10-07T07:59:34+0200"
    },
    "created_at": "2016-09-04T12:14:03+0200",
    "updated_at": "2016-10-09T03:03:00+0200"
}, {
    "id": 3,
    "username": "test2",
    "email": "test2@test.com",
    "enabled": false,
    "roles": [],
    "consumer": {
        "id": 3,
        "company_name": "test2",
        "company_siret": "02896452300006",
        "professional": true,
        "last_name": "TEST2",
        "first_name": "test2",
        "slug": "test2-test2",
        "created_at": "2016-10-07T03:22:32+0200",
        "updated_at": "2016-10-07T17:42:17+0200"
    },
    "created_at": "2016-10-07T17:28:08+0200",
    "updated_at": "2016-10-07T17:28:08+0200"
}, {
    "id": 4,
    "username": "ju",
    "email": "j.val@gmail.com",
    "enabled": true,
    "roles": [],
    "consumer": {
        "id": 4,
        "professional": false,
        "last_name": "Val",
        "first_name": "ju",
        "slug": "val-ju",
        "created_at": "2016-10-07T18:07:06+0200",
        "updated_at": "2016-10-07T18:07:06+0200"
    },
    "created_at": "2016-10-07T18:07:06+0200",
    "updated_at": "2016-10-07T18:07:06+0200"
}]
```

All works well, but I notice that If I am logged in with one of these users (for example **Val-Ju**), the query returns me **some other credentials and data** I don't specify in, for example:

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "username": "test",
    "email": "test@test.com",
    "enabled": true,
    "roles": [],
    "consumer": {
        "id": 1,
        "professional": false,
        "last_name": "TEST",
        "first_name": "test",
        "slug": "test-test",
        "created_at": "2016-10-07T03:22:32+0200",
        "updated_at": "2016-10-07T17:42:17+0200"
    },
    "created_at": "2016-10-02T07:28:28+0200",
    "updated_at": "2016-10-09T01:05:04+0200"
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "username": "admin",
    "email": "admin@test.com",
    "enabled": true,
    "roles": ["ROLE_ADMIN"],
    "consumer": {
        "id": 2,
        "company_name": "admin",
        "company_siret": "01234567890006",
        "professional": true,
        "last_name": "ADMIN",
        "first_name": "Admin",
        "slug": "admin-admin",
        "created_at": "2016-10-06T08:45:23+0200",
        "updated_at": "2016-10-07T07:59:34+0200"
    },
    "created_at": "2016-09-04T12:14:03+0200",
    "updated_at": "2016-10-09T03:03:00+0200"
}, {
    "id": 3,
    "username": "test2",
    "email": "test2@test.com",
    "enabled": false,
    "roles": [],
    "consumer": {
        "id": 3,
        "company_name": "test2",
        "company_siret": "02896452300006",
        "professional": true,
        "last_name": "TEST2",
        "first_name": "test2",
        "slug": "test2-test2",
        "created_at": "2016-10-07T03:22:32+0200",
        "updated_at": "2016-10-07T17:42:17+0200"
    },
    "created_at": "2016-10-07T17:28:08+0200",
    "updated_at": "2016-10-07T17:28:08+0200"
}, {
    "id": 4,
    "username": "ju",
    "username_canonical": "ju",
    "email": "j.val@gmail.com",
    "email_canonical": "j.val@gmail.com",
    "enabled": true,
    "salt": "5ng0rXXXXXXXXXXccwowscs4s",
    "password": "$2yXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX1HgIHe42rz\/agpB.0fC",
    "last_login": "2016-10-07T18:15:32+0200",
    "locked": false,
    "expired": false,
    "roles": [],
    "credentials_expired": false,
    "consumer": {
        "id": 4,
        "professional": false,
        "last_name": "Val",
        "first_name": "ju",
        "slug": "val-ju",
        "created_at": "2016-10-07T18:07:06+0200",
        "updated_at": "2016-10-07T18:07:06+0200"
    },
    "created_at": "2016-10-07T18:07:06+0200",
    "updated_at": "2016-10-07T18:15:32+0200"
}]
```

Of course, this is a thing I don't want, and it's a non-desired behavior.

> Why this behavior ocurred ?

Answer (score 1):

It's the default serialization configuration for FOSUserBundle, if you're logged in, it will serialize all your stuff.

What you need is to override this configuration. It can be done by adding

```
# src/MyBundle/Resources/config/serialization/Model.User.yml
FOS\UserBundle\Model\User:
    exclusion_policy: ALL
    properties:
        username:
            expose: true
            groups: ["aGroupIfNeeded"]
        #...
```

If you want more informations about [serialization groups](http://symfony.com/doc/current/serializer.html#using-serialization-groups-annotations).